# Firebase RealTime DataBase : Display objects who match a certain category (Angular)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Angular and Firebase and need some help :)

I can display all the elements from the database, but I also would like to display only specific elements : when a user click on a category (a new route bring him to a list of the elements in this category).

**This is my posts.service.ts :**

```
  postSubject = new Subject<Blog[]>();
  emitPosts() {
    this.postSubject.next(this.posts);
  }

    getPostsByCategory(category:string) {
      firebase.database().ref('/blog').orderByChild("category").equalTo(category).on("value", (data: Datasnapshot) => {
        this.posts = data.val() ? data.val() : [];
        console.log(this.posts)
        this.emitPosts();
      });
    }
```

**This is my component.ts :**

```
export class CategorylistComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  posts: Blog[];
  postsSubscription: Subscription;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private postsService: PostsService, private router: Router) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.postsSubscription = this.postsService.postSubject.subscribe(
      (posts:Blog[]) => {
        this.posts = posts;
    });
    const category = this.route.snapshot.params['category'];
    this.postsService.getPostsByCategory(category);
    this.postsService.emitPosts();
  }
```

**And my component.html :**

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let post of posts">
   <h3 class="card-header title">{{ post.title }}</h3>
   <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-title small">Catégorie: {{ post.category }}</p>
        <p class="card-text">{{ post.content }}</p>
        <p class="lien">En savoir plus :
        <a class="card-text lien" routerLink=[post.link]>{{ post.link }}</a></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

The console show me that it works, but it didn't display in the DOM. And I have a big error.

[We could see the 2 objects that match the category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMHeQ.png)

Thank you very much for your help :)
If necessary, this is my Github :
https://github.com/byrachel/devio

Comment: you are calling emitPosts twice, once in your component.ts and in your service. Make sure your posts have a title property.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Ramesh . 
- Yes but it works well like this in the component "blog" where I display all the elements without filter. I'm new to coding and try to understand how it works by testing and copying. I tried lots of things :)
- Yes there is a title property, and I can see it in the console.log().

Comment: try removing `this.postsService.emitPosts()` in your component.ts and inside subscribe where you assign posts to `this.posts`, `console.log(this.posts)` after assigning and check if you're getting the correct array.

Comment: @Ramesh Sorry it didn't work. This is what I have in the console : 
category Frameworks - posts [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]